# Tensorflow how to view results of model on test class

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and have taken my first pass at training a binary classifier with a custom dataset. I have followed the standard method of splitting into training, validation, and testing sets. With the "model" object I have, is there any way to see how it classified the test set? I know how to get/plot metrics like loss and accuracy, but I would like to see what it assigned to each image in the test set (which images in the test set it called 0 and 1, basically).

Comment: Hi @Ahmed Malik, Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#learning_curves) for the binary classification model and how the model performance is evaluated and plotted in test dataset? Thank you.